# Why when I use isset() with a constant fatal error is thrown?

Tags: php

I'm using isset() in my script, and if I use with a constant instead of a variable a fatal error seems to be thrown.

My Question:
Why when I use isset() with a constant fatal error is thrown?

```
<?php

switch($current_page) {
   case 'kb':
        define('TITLE', 'Knowledge Base');
        break;
   case 'edit':
        define('TITLE', 'Edit');
        break;
   case 'new':
        define('TITLE', 'New');
        break;
}
...
...
...
if (isset(TITLE)) {
    echo "<h1>".TITLE."</h1>";
}
```

I ran some tests, and see that both the constant and variable have same data type:

```
define('TITLE', 'Test');
$title = 'Test';

var_dump(TITLE); // string(4) "Test"
var_dump($title); // string(4) "Test"
```

I checked http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php and do not see anything that would account for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/isset)

> **Warning** 
> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to check if a [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) is defined then what you want to do is use the [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function rather than [`isset`](http://php.net/isset), as the name suggests.

```
if (defined(DEFINE)) {
    /** It is defined... **/
}
```